# Apache Server on Phone Hotspot

Tags: web-server

This might be too hard to answer if you can’t actually test a server on a hotspot, but can I make an Apache server on a hotspot and if yes, will the phone that is making the hotspot be able to access it?

Eddie

Comment: What has this to do with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Hey there @Ingo

Comment: @Ingo I am doing a project on Raspberry Pi and I need to make my own Apache server on a mobile hotspot. It’s probably not possible but I am asking just in case

Comment: You write: "*...will the phone that is making the hotspot...*". You will have an Apache Server on a phone that makes a hotspot. That's what I read.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have a mobile hotspot, and you wish to connect a raspbry pi to it, and use the pi as an apache server.

Using the pi as apache server is pretty well documented. Connecting the pi to a hotspot too.

The problem is the hotspot. Do you just want to serve systems that are connected to the same hotspot? In that case, make sure that client isolation is off.

If you want to serve pages to the rest of the Internet, it depends what is possible. If you can reach your hotspot from the Internet (so NOT from WiFi), then you could do port forwarding, if your hotspot supports it. I've seen it done with Androids phones. Nowadays, many telecom providers use CGNAT (Carrier Grade NAT), and if that is the case with your telecom provider, I would give up.

Comment: I’m just need to serve webpages to the phone making the hotspot. I’ll test it when I get back from my holidays tomorrow :) if it doesn’t work I’ll use IfTTT

Comment: @Eddie'sTech And does it work?